# Windows 10 AppInstaller: "An error occurred while accessing the file from the web"

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, appinstaller

I can install this app using the `.appxbundle`, but when I try to run the `.appinstaller` file locally, I get the following error:

> Cannot open app package: An error occurred while accessing the file from the web. Please try downloading and opening the file locally.

I am able to load both the `.appinstaller` and `.appxbundle` from the browser by navigating to the addresses defined in the `.appinstaller` file.

[image]

Comment: Could share your xml content about appinstaller file?

Comment: Due to network isolation, Windows 10 apps like App Installer are restricted to use IP loopback addresses like http://localhost/. When using local IIS Server, App Installer must be added to the loopback exempt list. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/web-install-iis#step-8---add-loopback-exemption-for-app-installer).

Answer (score 0):

Open your .appinstaller file with an editor. There has to be some important links, check files existence by your links. For example main package block:

```
<MainPackage Name="1243BZ3G.YourAppName" Version="1.0.11.0"
Publisher="Your publisher data" Uri="https://service.com/myapps/app_1.0.11.0_x64.appx" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
```

Check your **Uri** for file existence. There can be other **Uris**, like dependencies - check all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Right click the downloaded .appinstaller file and select Properties. At the bottom of the Properties window, check the 'Unblock' checkbox then click ok. Rerun the .appinstaller file and it should now install the program.

[image]